# Incorrect checksum when using calloc and free in a loop

Tags: c++, c, malloc

I declare a two-dimensional array a(m*n) in a `for` loop. When the `for` loop runs for the first time there is no problem, but the second time it generates an error. The program is:

```
for (int j=0; j<2; j++) {
    int **a = (int**)calloc(n,sizeof(int*));
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        a[i] = (int*)calloc(m,sizeof(int));
    }
    //...some operation to a[m,n] array
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        free(a[i]);
    free(a);
}
```

When the `for` loop runs for the second time, it runs to the line containing `calloc` and generates the following error on the console:

> malloc: *** error for object 0x94a8b14: incorrect checksum for freed 
>   object - object was probably modified after being freed

It makes no difference if I delete the lines containing `free`.

Comment: `a` has capacity for `n` pointers, but you loop over it as if it has `m`.

Comment: i edit the post , m is now n.

Comment: you should flag it C, not C++ by the way

Answer (score 5):

```
int **a=(int**)calloc(n,sizeof(int*));
                      ^
for(int i=0;i<m;i++){
              ^
    a[i]=(int*)calloc(m,sizeof(int));
      ^
```

This fails catastrophically if `n < m`.

Answer (score 2):

The line:

```
int **a=(int**)calloc(n,sizeof(int*));
```

creates an array of 'n' pointers to integer arrays. This is your 'n' dimension.

Your next step should be to iterate over each element in the array (of dimension 'n') and create an array of size 'm'. This will give you your 'm' dimension.

Your inner for loop:

```
for (int i=0; i<m; i++) {
```

actually iterates over 'm' elements of your array of size 'n'. This is incorrect. If you change this line to:

```
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
```

you should avoid your memory allocation errors. Don't forget to change 'm' to 'n' in the second inner for loop too (to free the correct amount of memory).